# How to refactor React JS code without bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

i have code with react-bootstrap:

```
 <ListGroup>
            {car.manufacturers.map(manufacturer =>
                <ListGroup.Item
                    style={{cursor:"pointer"}}
                    key={car.id}
                    active={manufacturer.id === car.selectedManufacturer.id}
                    onClick={() => car.SetSelectedManufacturer(manufacturer)}
                >
                    {manufacturer.name}
                </ListGroup.Item>
            )}
        </ListGroup>
```

But i prefer to use native layout. How to refactor for usage without bootstrap? I understood that **active** key just add a class to element, but i cant got how to make it in that case

Answer (score 0):

**the answer was:** (on example with border-bottom)

```
style={manufacturer.id === car.selectedManufacturer.id ? {borderBottom:"2px solid cyan"} : {borderBottom:"none"}}
```